# Problem connecting transformer output to CNN input in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I need to build a transformer-based architecture in Tensorflow following the encoder-decoder approach where the encoder is a preexisting Huggingface Distilbert model and the decoder is a CNN.

Inputs: a text containing texts with several phrases in a row. Outputs: codes according to taxonomic criteria. My data file has 7387 pairs text-label in TSV format:

```
text \t code
This is example text number one. It might contain some other phrases. \t C21
This is example text number two. It might contain some other phrases. \t J45.1
This is example text number three. It might contain some other phrases. \t A27
```

The remainder of the code is this:

```
        text_file = "data/datafile.tsv"
        with open(text_file) as f:
                lines = f.read().split("\n")[:-1]
                text_and_code_pairs = []
                for line in lines:
                        text, code = line.split("\t")
                        text_and_code_pairs.append((text, code))


        random.shuffle(text_and_code_pairs)
        num_val_samples = int(0.10 * len(text_and_code_pairs))
        num_train_samples = len(text_and_code_pairs) - 3 * num_val_samples
        train_pairs = text_and_code_pairs[:num_train_samples]
        val_pairs = text_and_code_pairs[num_train_samples : num_train_samples + num_val_samples]
        test_pairs = text_and_code_pairs[num_train_samples + num_val_samples :]

        train_texts = [fst for (fst,snd) in train_pairs]
        train_labels = [snd for (fst,snd) in train_pairs]
        val_texts = [fst for (fst,snd) in val_pairs]
        val_labels = [snd for (fst,snd) in val_pairs]
        test_texts = [fst for (fst,snd) in test_pairs]
        test_labels = [snd for (fst,snd) in test_pairs]

        distilbert_encoder = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-multilingual-cased")
        tokenizer = DistilBertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-multilingual-cased")

        train_encodings = tokenizer(train_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)
        val_encodings = tokenizer(val_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)
        test_encodings = tokenizer(test_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)

        train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
                dict(train_encodings),
                train_labels
        ))
        val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
                dict(val_encodings),
                val_labels
        ))
        test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((
                dict(test_encodings),
                test_labels
        ))

        model = build_model(distilbert_encoder)
        model.fit(train_dataset.batch(64), validation_data=val_dataset, epochs=3, batch_size=64)
        model.predict(test_dataset, verbose=1)
```

Lastly, the `build_model` function:

```
def build_model(transformer, max_len=512):
        model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        # Encoder
        inputs = layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32)
        distilbert = transformer(inputs)
        # LAYER - something missing here?
        # Decoder
        conv1D = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=10)(distilbert)
        pooling = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv1D)
        flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pooling)
        fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1255, activation='relu')(flat)
        softmax = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1255, activation='softmax')(fc)
        model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = softmax)
        model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(model.summary())
        return model
```

I managed to narrow down the possible locations of my problem. After changing from sequential to functional Keras API, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_transformer.py", line 99, in <module>
    main()
  File "keras_transformer.py", line 94, in main
    model = build_model(distilbert_encoder)
  File "keras_transformer.py", line 23, in build_model
    conv1D = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=10)(distilbert)
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 897, in __call__
    self._maybe_build(inputs)
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 2416, in _maybe_build
    self.build(input_shapes)  # pylint:disable=not-callable
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 152, in build
    input_shape = tensor_shape.TensorShape(input_shape)
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 771, in __init__
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 771, in <listcomp>
    self._dims = [as_dimension(d) for d in dims_iter]
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 716, in as_dimension
    return Dimension(value)
  File "/home/users/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py", line 200, in __init__
    None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got 'last_hidden_state'
```

It seems that the error lies in the connection between the output of the transformer and the input of the convolutional layer. Am I supposed to include another layer between them so as to adapt the output of the transformer? If so, what would be the best option?I'm using tensorflow==2.2.0, transformers==4.5.1 and Python 3.6.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is to call the right tensor for the tensorflow layer after the `dilbert` instance. Because `distilbert = transformer(inputs)` returns an instance rather than a tensor like in `tensorflow`, e.g., `pooling = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv1D)`. `pooling` is the output tensor of the `MaxPooling1D` layer.

I fix your problem by calling the `last_hidden_state` variable of the `distilbert` instance  (i.e. output of the `dilbert` model), and this will be your input to the next `Conv1D` layer.

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3' # suppress Tensorflow messages

from transformers import TFDistilBertModel, DistilBertModel
import tensorflow as tf

distilbert_encoder = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained("distilbert-base-multilingual-cased")


def build_model(transformer, max_len=512):
        # model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
        # Encoder
        inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), dtype=tf.int32)
        distilbert = transformer(inputs)
        # Decoder
        ###### !!!!!! #########
        conv1D = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=10)(distilbert.last_hidden_state) 
        ###### !!!!!! #########        
        pooling = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(conv1D)
        flat = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pooling)
        fc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1255, activation='relu')(flat)
        softmax = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1255, activation='softmax')(fc)
        model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs = inputs, outputs = softmax)
        model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=5e-5), loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
        print(model.summary())
        return model


model = build_model(distilbert_encoder)
```

This returns,

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 512)]             0         
_________________________________________________________________
tf_distil_bert_model (TFDist TFBaseModelOutput(last_hi 134734080 
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 503, 5)            38405     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 251, 5)            0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 1255)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1255)              1576280   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1255)              1576280   
=================================================================
Total params: 137,925,045
Trainable params: 137,925,045
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Note: I assume you mean `tf.keras.layers.Input` by `layers.Input` in your `build_model` function.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right. The problem seems to be the input to the Conv1D layer.

According to [the documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/distilbert.html#tfdistilbertmodel) the outputs.last_hidden_state has a shape of  (batch_size, sequence_length, hidden_size).
Conv1D is expecting an input of shape (batch_size, sequence_length).
Maybe you could resolve the problem by either changing your Conv1D to Conv2D or adding a Conv2D layer in between.

Comment: Either if add a Conv2D layer or if I swap the existing Conv1D layer for a Conv2D one, I get the following error relative to the line defining the Conv2D layer: 

```ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 512, 768]```